# CasperJS: clicking checkbox not triggering events as it does in browser

Tags: casperjs

I am trying to automate a process in CasperJS. However, I am facing some discrepancy between the behavior on a real browser vs the same in CasperJS.

**Update: Process works fine with slimerJS but gives issue with headless**

Here is my script:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    "waitTimeout": 10000
});

var inputElements = {
    "url": "http://www.jabong.com/incult-Tapered-Jeans-In-Indigo-1032119.html?pos=4",
    "size": "34",
    "address": {
        "email": "someemail@xyz.com"
    }    
}

casper.options.viewportSize = {width: 1679, height: 902};

casper.start(inputElements.url, function (){
    this.wait(10000, function (){
        console.log("loaded");
    })
});

var x = require('casper').selectXPath;

var sizeToSelect = inputElements.size;

// select size
casper.thenClick(x("//*[contains(@class,'size-desktop')]//"+
  "li[contains(@class,'first') and contains(@class,'popover-options')]//"+
  "span[contains(text(),'"+sizeToSelect+"')]/"+
".."));

// add to bag
casper.thenClick(x("//*[@id='add-to-cart']"));

// view cart
casper.thenClick(x("//*[@id='header-bag-sec']/a"))

// take a screenshot
casper.then(function() {
    console.log("saving screenshot");
  this.capture('../../1_view_cart.png');
});

casper.then(function() {
  console.log('clicked ok, new location is ' + this.getCurrentUrl());
});

// place order
casper.then(function (){
    this.click("[href='https://www.jabong.com/checkout/']");
})

// take a screenshot
casper.then(function() {
    console.log("saving screenshot");
  this.capture('../../2_address_details.png');
});

casper.then(function (){
    this.sendKeys("#login-email", inputElements.address.email);
})

casper.then(function (){
    this.click("#do-guest-checkout");
});

// take a screenshot
casper.then(function() {
    console.log("saving screenshot");
  this.capture('../../3_guest_checkout.png');   
});

casper.waitFor(function check() {
    return this.evaluate(function() {
        return document.querySelector('#btn-login-checkout').textContent == "Continue as Guest";
    });
}, function then() {
    this.click('#btn-login-checkout');
});


casper.run();
```

On the last page, clicking on checkbox "Checkout as Guest" on a browser removes the password input field and changes the text of the Login button to "Continue as Guest". Attached screenshot:

[image]

However, in CasperJS, the password input field and the Login button are not changing. Any idea what am I doing wrong ?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the `<label>` around the `<input>` element?

Comment: Yes, still the same. Strange this is that its working perfectly with SlimerJS but not with PhantomJS

Comment: strangely, clicking using xpath instead of CSS selector is working fine